# Hidden Markov Model Semantics

Tags: model, hidden-markov-model

I've been using a program that utilizes an HMM to predict the locations of gene coding regions on a DNA sequence. When writing about it, I want to make sure that I have the terminology correct.

The program has the ability to be trained for any species, and it also has been pre-trained for many well-known species. I want to know how to refer to these different 'trainings' in the plural form, for example when comparing them.

Is there a word for this?

During training, the parameters of the model are estimated, correct? I am nearly 100% sure that 'parametrization' is NOT the word I'm looking for, since that goes against what I understand parametrization to mean, but that's what I find myself wanting to say, e.g. the human parametrization vs the worm parametrization. I also could refer to them as different 'models', but I'm unsure if that's correct, either. I appreciate any input.

Note: I recently asked this Q on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181072/hidden-markov-model-semantics?noredirect=1#comment4486650_2181072), but was told it'd be more likely to be answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that:

*"I have a software that can predict gene coding regions on a DNA sequence. It uses the HMM model. It has been pre-trained for various well-known species, each give a **different** **model**. The model includes state diagram, transition probabilities, and emission probabilities."*

I don't think your well-known species assume the same state diagram. Although they share HMM properties, they are very different in terms of how the model works. For instance, you can't use HMM trained on sapiens on flies.

**Short answer:** different HMM model.

Comment: Thank you. It was not clear to me that the state diagram would change or that they would be considered different models.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the word *tuned*. When you train a model on some data, you are basically tuning the parameters to that data. You can also used the word *trained*, as in trained on a particular dataset.